# Creating a Column in a Dataframe Based on a Conditional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,1,0,1],
          "B":[-1,0,0,0],
          "C":[0,0,0,0]},
         index = [.1,.2,.3, .4])
```

The way I first logically approached the problem

```
for index, row in iterrows():
    if df['A'] == 1:
        df['C'] == 1
    elif df['B'] == -1
        df['C'] == -1
    else:
        df['C'] == 0
```

I want

```
pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,1,0,1],
          "B":[-1,0,0,0],
          "C":[-1,1,0,1]},
         index = [.1,.2,.3, .4])
```

After trying the first method I tried a variety of methods proposed in other questions, but none seem to fit my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use nested `np.where` calls:

```
df.C = np.where(df.A == 1, 1, np.where(df.B == -1, -1, 0))
df
     A  B  C
0.1  0 -1 -1
0.2  1  0  1
0.3  0  0  0
0.4  1  0  1
```

---

**Performance**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000)

%timeit np.select([df.A == 1, df.B == -1], [1, -1])
100 loops, best of 3: 5.25 ms per loop

%timeit np.where(df.A == 1, 1, np.where(df.B == -1, -1, 0))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.86 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['C'] = pd.np.select([df.A == 1, df.B == -1], [1, -1])

df
#       A    B   C
#0.1    0   -1  -1
#0.2    1    0   1
#0.3    0    0   0
#0.4    1   -1   1
```